Transition Probabilities for a Stochastic Rumor Model
I am currently working on an exercise involving a stochastic model for the spread of a rumor among a group of 6 friends, where initially only one person knows the rumor at time $n = 0$. At each step, two individuals are randomly selected to interact. If one person knows the rumor and the other does not, the rumor is transmitted with a probability of $\frac{3}{10}$.
Let $X_n$ represent the number of people who have heard the rumor at time $n$.
I need to find the transition probabilities $P_{ij}$ of the Markov chain $\{X_n, n \geq 0\}$. The anwser is
$$
P = \begin{bmatrix}
\frac{9}{10} & \frac{1}{10} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \frac{21}{25} & \frac{4}{25} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \frac{41}{50} & \frac{9}{50} & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{21}{25} & \frac{4}{25} & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{9}{10} & \frac{1}{10} \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Could anyone help me understand how to arrive at this matrix or provide insights on calculating these probabilities?
Thank you

I don't know a Markov Chain from a giraffe.  On the other hand, for $~k \in {1,2,3,4,5,6},~$ it looks like you are supposed to consider the function $$f(k) = 1 - \left[ ~\frac{k(6-k)}{\binom{6}{2}} \times \frac{3}{10} ~\right].$$

Thank you so much for your help. I thought I would need to multiply by 7/10 since the number of people who know the rumor doesn’t change along the diagonal.

At each step, the number of people that know the rumor either increases by one or does not change. For it to increase, the two individuals who interact (of which there are $\binom62$ possible pairs) must consist of one who knows the rumor (of which there are $k$) and one who doesn't (of which there are $6-k$), and then the rumor must succeed in spreading (the probability of which is $\frac3{10}$). Thus the probability that it spreads is
$$P_{k,k+1}=\frac{k(6-k)}{\binom62}\cdot\frac3{10}=\frac{k(6-k)}{50},$$
and the probability that it doesn't spread is $P_{k,k}=1-P_{k,k+1}$.
